# Custom Functions in Thread

Tags: java, android

I have a simple Question:

I have a Thread named rlMF. I created it this way:

```
public Thread rlMF = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        reloadMissingFiles();
        stopTh();
    }

    public void stopTh() {
        activityStopped = true;
    }
});
```

Now i want to call the stopTh Function from outer Thread. Why can't i simply call rlMF.stopTh(); and what can i do else?

Example:

```
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d("Info", "destroying...");
    activityStopped = true;
    rlMF.stopTh();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Is not working...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to interrupt your thread when onPause is called?

Comment: Yes, thats what i want to do...

Comment: see my answer about various approaches to do that.

Answer (score 2):

Because the interface accessible is from `Thread`. In order to have you method accessible from out, you need to specify a type that exposes this method.

And if you take a look carefully the method is implemented in the instance of `Runnable`. Not even in `Thread`.

You could have something like this if you really need to access the `Runnable` object:

```
class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
    ...
    }

    public void fooBar() {
    ...
    }       
}

public void someMethod() {
    MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
    Thread thread = new Thread(myRunnable);
    ...
    myRunnable.fooBar();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does it needs to be a new class?

Comment: would be the cleaner solution for it... ;)

Comment: That fixes the code but does not address the ultimate goal which is to interrupt the thread from onPause.

Comment: I found the mistake. The reloadMissingFiles() was synchronized and thats why my Application crashed all time....

Answer (score 0):

An example for Francisco approach, besides what you are trying to achieve. Maybe this can point you in the right direction

```
public class CustomRun implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        reloadMissingFiles();
        stopTh();
    }

    public void stopTh() {
        activityStopped = true;
    }
}
```

In your Code

```
// start thread with custom runner
CustomRun runner = new CustomRun();
new Thread(runner).start();

// call your stopTh method on CustomRun class
protected void onPause() {
    Log.d("Info", "destroying...");
    activityStopped = true;
    runner.stopTh();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to interrupt the thread from `onPause`. There are several ways to do it, but essentially, you will need to include some interruptibility in `reloadMissingFiles`.

**Option 1**

You can use a boolean flag like you did - you need to declare it as `volatile` to make sure the changes are visible across threads:

```
private volatile boolean activityStopped = false;

public void reloadMissingFiles() {
    while (!activityStopped) {
       //load small chunks so that the activityStopped flag is checked regularly
    }
}

public Thread rlMF = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        reloadMissingFiles(); //will exit soon after activityStopped has been set to false
    }
});

protected void onPause() {
    //This will stop the thread fairly soon if the while loop in
    //reloadMissingFiles is fast enough
    activityStopped = true;
    super.onPause();
}
```

**Option 2 (better approach)**

I don't know what you do in `reloadMissingFiles`, but I suppose it is some sort of I/O operations, which are generally interruptible. You can then have an interruption policy where you stop as soon as an InterruptedException is caught:

```
public void reloadMissingFiles() {
    try {
        //use I/O methods that can be interrupted
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //cleanup specific stuff (for example undo the operation you started
        //if you don't have time to complete it
        //then let the finally block clean the mess
    } finally {
        //cleanup (close the files, database connection or whatever needs to be cleaned
    }
}

public Thread rlMF = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        reloadMissingFiles(); //will exit when interrupted
    }
});

protected void onPause() {
    runner.interrupt(); //sends an interruption signal to the I/O operations
    super.onPause();
}
```

Note: you can also read [this article](http://forward.com.au/javaProgramming/HowToStopAThread.html) for a more in depth version of it.